# How to associate a stripe customer when using the embedded pricing lists on your site?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am creating a registration system to log into a portal(using laravel backend) with stripe. This is a subscription site.

**The steps for registration are as follows:**

1. User fills in registration form and submits it.
2. The account for the portal is created
3. A customer in stripe is created using the stripe API's and the account on the portal is updated with the new stripe customer ID.
4. The customer is then directed to the embedded price file code snipit provided stripe. This allows the customer to select and pay for the subscription.

Here is the Embeded code we used during step #4

```
<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
<stripe-pricing-table 
pricing-table-id="prctbl_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
publishable-key="pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
customer_id={customer_id}
</stripe-pricing-table>
```

I was expecting stipe to create a customer with the selected plan. Instead, it created 2 customers. The first was created during step 3 as expected. The second customer was created again in step 4. The outcome from step 4 is to just have the existing customer add a plan to their account. I am passing the customer ID above in the embedded code. Why is this still choosing to create a second customer in stripe?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from [this section in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/no-code/pricing-table#customer-session) that feature is limited to a private beta program.  I would recommend contacting the email address that is listed in that doc if you want to be considered for inclusion in the Beta program.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of how normally one would move through the registration using the price lists? I was thinking about just performing the pricing list, let it create the new customer and then use webhook or having it return back and using the session id to then load the sripe customer id in the portals user account.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by price lists.  The product you were referring to in your ask is the Pricing Table (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table).  I'm also not sure what you mean by "registration" or the "portals user account".